# Intellij IDEA export list of recent projects

Tags: python, java, android, intellij-idea

Does anyone know how I can export or where I can copy (backup) a file with "list of recent projects"
If I uninstall and reinstall Intellij IDEA, I don't want to create all groups / project lists from scratch - maybe in that case I could overwrite the backup file and then my list with "recent projects" would appear when starting Intellij.

[image: INTELLIJ RECENT PROJECTS WINDOW]

Answer (score 1):

The list is stored in the `recentProjects.xml` file of the IDE [config folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory):

For macOS: `/Users/JohnS/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1/options/recentProjects.xml`

For Windows: `C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.1\options\recentProjects.xml`